# Error creating an executable python script with PyInstaller due to PyBluez error

Tags: python, bluetooth, pyinstaller, executable, pybluez

I have created a functional python (Python 3.10.4) script that uses Pybluez (version 0.30) to connect to an ESP32. Now I want to use PyInstaller to create a standalone executable application from said script, but I keep running into the following error when executing the command:

*pyinstaller scriptname.py*

Error:
*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\X\Python3\lib\site-packages\pybluez-0.30-py3.10-win-amd64.egg\bluetooth\widcomm.py'*

In the **Python3\lib\site-packages** directory, there is a pybluez-0.30-py3.10-win-amd64.egg file, but it contains no sub folders (**bluetooth\widcomm.py**).

Any help regarding this error would be much appreciated. Let me know if any additional information is required.

Thank You

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstall Pybluez and use a stable version, e.g. `pybluez==0.23`, or add `widcomm.py` manually https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/bluetooth/widcomm.py.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get a **"Error in Pybluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid"** error when running the command **pip install pybluez 0.23**. Also, how can I manually add the **widcomm.py** since the **pybluez-0.30-py3.10-win-amd64.egg** file is only a file and not a folder?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve the mentioned problem, and here is how.

1. An .egg file is basically like a zip file that contains sub folders and files. I had to download a software called **ALZip** (https://alzip.en.softonic.com/) to view the contents of the .egg file, which showed that the bluetooth/widcomm.py was in fact present in the .egg file.
2. *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\X\Python3\lib\site-packages\pybluez-0.30-py3.10-win-amd64.egg\bluetooth\widcomm.py'*

had an issue with the name of the **pybluez-0.30-py3.10-win-amd64.egg** file so I solved it by **Extracting** the .egg file to a new folder, and renaming the folder to "***pybluez-0.30-py3.10-win-amd64.egg***" (yes the .egg should be part of the name as well)

These steps managed to solve the error and I was able to create an exe from my Python Script using pyinstaller. (**pyinstaller scriptname.py**)